# Unable to install PuTTY on windows

Tags: putty, windows-installer

Trying to install `putty` in my 64-bit windows 8.

On choosing destination folder it shows error and says:

> Installation directory must be on a local hard drive.

I have chosen default folder i.e: `C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\`

I downloaded package file of `MSI` extension from this [website](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/releases/0.70.html)

Answer (score 0):

I ran a test-install of the 64-bit version (MSI installer), and I even set it to install to the 32-bit path you specified above, no problems (the correct 64-bit path is `C:\Program Files\PuTTY\` not `C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\` which is the 32-bit path). Are you running the x86-32bit installer perhaps? I ran the 64-bit one.

Try to enable logging for your setup to see what is going on. Launch the install from `CMD.EXE` (command prompt).

**Sample install command** (to enable logging with paths you must replace):

```
msiexec.exe /I "C:\YourInstaller.msi" /QN /L*V "C:\msilog.log"
```

**Quick Parameter Explanation**:

```
/I = run install sequence
/QN = run completely silently
/L*V "C:\msilog.log"= verbose logging at path specified
```

If there are any flagged and obvious errors in the log you can search for "value 3" first to check. If not, then the log must be investigated in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the putty download page
https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html

scroll down to 'alternative binary files'

Download putty.exe and drag/drop to the location you require. Create shortcut on desktop if required.

Comment: Certainly, at the expense of not getting the PATH variable updated so you need to do that yourself as well - in addition to creating the required shortcuts manually. And you lose the association to PPK files (to allow right click file options for *.PPK files). But yes, that would be a simple way to get going if requirements are simple.

Comment: Sure beats the hell out of having to deal with msiexec logging, which is far more painful than a shortcut and simple file extension association and 'path add %path%;c:\path_to_putty'. 

 As you are using Win8 where the permissions are at best, random - try right clicking the msi and run as admin.

Comment: I suppose, I guess it depends on his deployment scope? (how many computers he needs to deploy to). Running the MSI elevated could indeed help, but the MSI should trigger a UAC prompt on its own I think (there could be complications). But yes, if the deployment scope is a single computer, maybe he can use the binary as you suggest and set up things manually. I think learning to deal with MSI logging can be very helpful in the future though. Besides I would really like to know what that log says.